# List of base classes for use with variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, c++11

Is there a way to access all base classes of a class in C++?
Since variadic templates are available I think it would make sense to have e.g. ___BASE which is a variadic list of all types the current class does derive from.
This would also enable a check whether a class or it's base classes are of a certain type.
Is this already possible or am I missing something here why this isn't possible!?

Comment: I do not think it is possible due to private inheritance. Multiple inheritance might cause problems.

Comment: Multiple inheritance is the reason why I said it should be variadic. I don't see any problem with private inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a general mechanism in the language that'll tell you all the base classes, though you're free to add a suitable typedef to all members of your class hierarchy that will make this information available (e.g. typedef a tuple whose argument types are the ancestor plus the ancestor's ancestors) -- you could probably write a little mixin for that.

As for checking whether something is a base of another, that's already part of the standard in the shape of the `std::is_base_of` type trait.